# How to reflect on a class from an imported package with a private constructor?

Tags: reflection, dart, flutter, dart-mirrors

I am using the `reflectable` library to reflect on types from imported packages (like `analysis_server_client` or `flutter`). I can reflect on types that have public constructors like `Notification` or `Request` (from the `analysis_server_client` package). I reflect on those types by extending those types and then using the `superclassQuantifyCapability` capability.

However, I am not able to reflect on types that have a private constructor like `Icons` (from the `flutter` package) since I cannot extend them. Is there a way to reflect on types like `Icons` that have a private constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to use the `GlobalQuantifyCapability` which lets you declare which members to generate reflection on. It works on classes with private constructors as well. Some sample code:

```
@GlobalQuantifyCapability(r"^.(SomeClass|SomeEnum)", reflector)
import 'package:reflectable/reflectable.dart';

import 'package:some_package/some_class.dart';
import 'package:some_package/some_enum.dart';

class Reflector extends Reflectable {
  const Reflector() : super(declarationsCapability, ...);
}
const reflector = const Reflector();
```